# Rules of url rewriting in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it Required to use '?' sign for query string in `Asp.net` with `C#` ?

and can its possible to convert my query string

> > www.xyz.com/test.aspx?name=rajeev

to

> > www.xyz.com/rajeev or www.xyz.com/name=rajeev

Comment: Yes you can convert it like that using URL rewrite from IIS.

Comment: after ?is the start of parameter, it use to define your start of parameter, / normally indicting sub folder. but anyway, yes, you can use IIS URL rewrite function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `?name=rajeev` **is** a query string. If you don't use a `?` it's not a query string.
- `/name/rajeev` **isn't** a query string, but it's a **path** ([see ASP.NET routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or [IIS URL rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)).
- `/name=rajeev` is just a path with a custom way to specify name's value. I would avoid this: you're going to avoid a lot of issues if you choose one of two approaches above.

Also check what saids the [URI standard RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4):

> [...] The query component is indicated by the first question mark ("?") character and terminated by a number sign ("#") character or by the end of the URI.

That is `?` character isn't an ASP.NET requirement if you want to use query strings in your URLs, but it's the standard across all plataforms and languages.

Comment: thanks sir, can you please give me a sort example for the particular query strings i am using asp.net with c#.

Comment: @RajeevMehta No problem man ;) Now I'm at work and I won't be able to take that time to show you a sample. BTW, the link of ASP.NET routing I've provided you should be enough. Take your time!! :D

Answer (score 0):

```
For converting the url www.xyz.com/test.aspx?name=rajeev to www.xyz.com/rajeev
This can be done by Creating Rewrite Rules for the URL Rewrite Module in IIS.
```

[Please read this link.](http://salopek.eu/content/26/introduction-to-url-rewriting-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-and-regular-expressions)